# Autologin user after completion of WordPress Gravity Form registration form

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

Recently a function has fallen over.

Our client is focused on lead generation, and gates brochure downloads and digital resources, requiring a user to register to gain access.

Previously, when users registered, the custom code below would automatically log them in. Now, it redirects them back to the login form, which delivers poor user experience.

The following custom code previously logged users in automatically:

```
// Auto login registered users via Gravity Forms
add_action( 'gform_user_registered', 'wpc_gravity_registration_autologin',  10, 4 );
/**
 * Auto login after registration.
 */
function wpc_gravity_registration_autologin( $user_id, $user_config, $entry, $password ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_login = $user->user_login;
    $user_password = $password;
       $user->set_role(get_option('default_role', 'subscriber'));

    wp_signon( array(
        'user_login' => $user_login,
        'user_password' =>  $user_password,
        'remember' => true

    ) );
}
```

This is operational on the URL - [www.spaciotempo.co.uk/my-account/](http://www.spaciotempo.co.uk/my-account/)

According to Gravity Forms support: To improve form submission performance, version 5.1, moved feed processing to the background by default. This means the feeds are processed in a separate request, where the user isn't present.

Auto-login isn't compatible with background feed processing because the current user object and auth cookie are set in the request where the user isn't present.

You can use the following filter to disable background feed processing for the add-on, so the feed will be processed in the same request as the form submission.

More info here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_is_feed_asynchronous/#disable-for-user-registration-auto-login

I’ve added the code below as recommended at the above URL and it still isn’t working:

```
// New auto login code add_filter( 'gform_is_feed_asynchronous', function ( $is_asynchronous, $feed ) { if ( ! $is_asynchronous || rgar( $feed, 'addon_slug' ) !== 'gravityformsuserregistration' ) { return $is_asynchronous; } return gf_user_registration()->is_update_feed( $feed ) ? $is_asynchronous : false; }, 10, 2 );
```

Why is the addition of the above code in the functions.php file of the active child theme not auto-logging in users, as expected?

Comment: Rather than using comments to add information to your question, please [edit] it.